# Do I need to install anything for `import glob` to work under Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-import, glob

I am a total novice with Raspberry Pi, I'm importing and combining a couple of programs together, working with Python 3 and VIM.  One of the programs has a code line that reads:

```
import os, glob, date, time.
```

How do I import GLOB for Windows 10 so I can work on my laptop?  I'm sure I will have a few hundred more questions but this is where I think I have to start.
Thanks Gaggle,
Barry

Comment: I am confused... are you trying to be able to connect your Pi to Windows, or get Windows to run on your Pi?  I am guessing the first, but then `glob` likely does not apply, given that it appears to do with shell programming.  Anyway, you may have more luck over at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please don't yell.

Comment: Hi Josh & Gaggle:  I am running VIM on a laptop that is running Windows 10.  I wish to write my program on the laptop using VIM.  Then copy the code over to the RPi.  So, Part 1:  Can I run the program, just to see if it will run on the laptop?  Part 2: When I copy it to the RPi, and run it, it does not recognize the line:  import os, glob, date, time.

Answer (score 3):

[glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) is part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html), it thus comes pre-installed with Python, whether you run Python on Windows, macOS, Linux, or whatever..